# Collision detection between two SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I have to detect collision between two  SKSpriteNode(***wall***, ***man***) which is the child of a SKNode ***background***. The ***background*** node is child of main SKScene ***gameScene*** class. When I want to detect collision using the method

```
- (void) didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else  {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }
    NSLog(@"contact happened");
}
```

But no collision detection is found. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably having one of two issues:

1. You didn't set the `contactDelegate` property of your `SKPhysicsWorld` object.
2. You didn't set your category and contact test bits correctly.

Here's how to set the category and contact test bits:

```
#define kCategoryOne (1 << 0)
#define kCategoryTwo (1 << 1)

bodyA.categoryBitMask = kCategoryOne;
bodyA.contactTestBitMask = kCategoryTwo;

bodyB.categoryBitMask = kCategoryTwo;
bodyB.contactTestBitMask = kCategoryOne;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. SKPhysicsContactDelegate is incompatible type of background. Where my background is SKNode class. self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self.prepareBackgroundObj; Here it showing warning message.

Comment: You need to set the contact delegate to whichever object implements the `didBeginContact` method, and you need that object's class `@interface` declaration to include the `<SKPhysicsContactDelegate>` protocol.

Comment: Using #defines for the categories is a bad choice, you lose type checking when you do this. A better option is to create a bit mask using NS_OPTIONS

Comment: But if we use <SKPhysicsContactDelegate> protocol in the **background** sknode then it shows error message "property physicsWorld not found on the object type background"